# Reading LaTeX expression and pretty printing it as ASCII with python

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I'm running some python code in the terminal and I want to output a pretty ASCII representation of a LaTeX expression.  I realize I can pop up a separate window using matplotlib, but I don't want the text in a separate window.  Sympy does a nice job printing, but doesn't seem to import LaTeX (at least not that I've found).

Ideally, It would work something like this:

```
print('$x^2$')
```

would output in the console:

```
 2
x
```

Just like sympy would if I made a sympy symbol x and printed x**2.

More complicated expressions would have to be handled appropriately.  For example:

```
\lim_{n \to \inf} \sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}
```

could be rendered as:

```
        n
       -----
       \      1
lim     >   -----
n->inf /      x
       -----
        x=1
```

Characters which are not supported in ASCII such as $\alpha$ could be expanded to an ASCII equivalent such as "alpha" or an error could be thrown.

Comment: Can you list the kind of latex expressions you want converted and then convert them to sympy strings...the example you have can be easily converted...

Comment: What should happen if the input includes any of the many, many features of LaTeX that are difficult or impossible to represent in pure ASCII? Greek letters, differently-sized characters, etc. Something like `$lim_{n \to \inf} \sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x}$` would be completely unworkable.

Comment: I'll edit the question to address more complicated expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX parsing is not currently included in SymPy, although it has been [speculated since 2012](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Parsing#types-of-things-to-parse) with a decently high priority.

The third-party [latex2sympy](https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy) may be able to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Using something like latex2sympy and then SymPy's pretty printer (`pprint(expr, use_unicode=False)` will pretty print an expression using just ASCII characters) should work, although note that SymPy does not completely preserve the form of input expressions, so the output may be different (although mathematically equivalent) from the input (for instance, it may rearrange terms).

Comment: Seems to work.  It would be nice to have it built into sympy.